# Where are the .java files after compiling a .jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, compilation, javadoc

I am making a little webchat using JSP and I would like to know where the .java files are located after compiling the .jsp files to run javadoc on them; but I dont know where they are, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

They will usually be in a "work" or "temp" dir of your web server.

In can case of tomcat there are in a "work" dir. Example: `apache-tomcat-7.0.59\work\Catalina\localhost`

If you are Eclipse and deploying to Tomcat from Eclipse, then they will be in a dir in your project workspace. Example: `myproject\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost`